# stream-added never gets triggered with agora.io

Tags: javascript, agora.io

I have:

```
        this.agoraClient = AgoraRTC.createClient({ mode: "rtc", codec: "h264" })

        this.agoraClient.on('stream-added', (evt) => {
            console.log('SHAMOON added stream', evt)
            this.remoteStream = evt.stream
            this.agoraClient.subscribe(this.remoteStream)
        })


        this.agoraClient.on('stream-subscribed', (evt) => {
            console.log('SHAMOON subscribed stream', evt)
            this.remoteStream.play(this.remoteHtmlElementId, { muted: true });
        })
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.agoraClient.init(this.appId, resolve, reject))
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.agoraClient.join(null, this.channelName, this.uid, resolve, reject))

        this.localStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
            streamID: this.uid,
            audio: true,
            video: false,
            screen: false
        })


        await new Promise(this.localStream.init)
        this.localStream.play(this.localHtmlElementId, { muted: true })
        console.log('playing local')


        this.agoraClient.publish(this.localStream)
        console.log('publishing local')
```

And it gets to `publishing local`, but the `SHAMOON added stream` never gets called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stream-added` callback is only triggered when a remote stream is added to the channel. The event you want to listen for is the `stream-published` event which is when the local stream is added to the channel.

```js
this.agoraClient.on('stream-published', function (evt) {
  console.log("local stream published successfully");
});
```